# People can edit my form and send a string that is different from an email that mess up my databases

Tags: php, mysql, email

My form requires an email(set via input type) however people use Inspect Element and submit other values that are not email. One of them is the percent sign and it messes up with my databases badly. I tried checking for the percent sign but it didnt help. Here's my code, could you please give me a lead or tell me what's wrong?

Thanks

```
if(strpos($_POST['email'], '&#37;') == false) 
{
    $curpass = strtoupper(hash("whirlpool", $_POST['curpass']));
    $passii = $con->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `playerinfo` WHERE `PlayerName` = ?;");
    $passii->execute(array($_SESSION["playername"]));
    while($row = $passii->fetch())
    {
        $curpass1 = $row['password'];
    }
    if($curpass == $curpass1)
    {
        $email = mysql_escape_string($pemail);
        echo "<div class='flash_success'>Your email has been changed.</div>";
        $p_name_settings = $_SESSION['playername'];
        $updatemail = $con->prepare("UPDATE `playerinfo` SET `email` = ? WHERE `PlayerName` = ?");
        $updatemail->execute(array($pemail, $_SESSION["playername"]));
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class='flash_error'>You did not enter your current password correctly. Settings were not saved.</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you define "_messes up with my databases badly_".

Comment: `if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //error }`

Comment: Always validate your data server-side to make sure the data you're getting is the data you expect.

Comment: You need to use salt when hashing passwords.

Comment: You should always assume anything given through user input is malicious and perform checks server side after submissions. Client settings help guide the user, but should not be seen as a line of defence

Comment: It's really important to use === when using the strpos function, because it will return 0 if the string being searched for starts at the 1st character. The extra = will check to see if it returns false instead of 0, because in this case it matters.

Comment: You're mixing different mysql apis here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` and `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` to prevent that insertion. Something like:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

// Remove all illegal characters from email
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

// Validate e-mail
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // email is a valid email address
    $curpass = strtoupper(hash("whirlpool", $_POST['curpass']));
    $passii = $con->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `playerinfo` WHERE `PlayerName` = ?;");
    $passii->execute(array($_SESSION["playername"]));
    while($row = $passii->fetch())
    {
        $curpass1 = $row['password'];
    }
    if($curpass == $curpass1)
    {
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
        echo "<div class='flash_success'>Your email has been changed.</div>";
        $p_name_settings = $_SESSION['playername'];
        $updatemail = $con->prepare("UPDATE `playerinfo` SET `email` = ? WHERE `PlayerName` = ?");
        $updatemail->execute(array($pemail, $_SESSION["playername"]));
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class='flash_error'>You did not enter your current password correctly. Settings were not saved.</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `mysql_escape_string()` that doesn't mix with any other api than `mysql_`, so this line `$email = mysql_escape_string($pemail);` won't work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good catch! I'll fix that part.

Comment: I made a slight edit to the function. It needs a db connection as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($email !== false) {
    //do action
}
```